# Hybris server is stuck when I restart it

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I stop my server update when it was creating DDL statments and restart the server. Now my server is stuck at below line. I did `ant clean all` and again tried to start the server but still same issue.

How to resolve this?

```
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
Feb 07, 2020 2:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags is already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Feb 07, 2020 2:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 07, 2020 2:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Comment: Try with `ant updatesystem`  if you want to update with specific options then you can pass the JSON in the same command `ant updatesystem -DconfigFile="/path/to/json/file.json"`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following SQL request to check if the system is locked.

```
select process,locked from systeminit ;
```

if locked = 1, update it to 0.